# Apply class in table tag with redactor in YiiBooster

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, htmlpurifier, redactor, yii-booster

I am using Redactor which came along with YiiBooster.
I want to apply class in table as 'table table-striped'.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to code view. First button in toolbar. Then add class to table tag:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
```

Comment: well, i don't want to give html view for normal users. So, I was wondering whether redactor has any option to apply default class to tags.

Answer (score 0):

No ready to go answer, but i got this from the [Redactor website](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/#api-observeTables):

> Launch an event that listens to inserted tables and allows to edit them.

If you use the [official Yii Redactor Extension](https://github.com/yiiext/imperavi-redactor-widget) you have to set the ID manual in the widget:

```
$this->widget('ImperaviRedactorWidget', array(
    'id'=>'redactor-widget',
    ...
));
```

The you can invoke the code like this:

```
$('#redactor-widget').redactor('observeTables');
```

Comment: Please explain, how to proceed after $('#redactor-widget').redactor('observeTables');